# cannot resolve MyFirebaseMessagingService

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nazriel.sadio_v1">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".activities.homescreen_activity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.SignInActivity" />

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


</application>
```

I had this `FirebaseMessaging service` working a few days ago and now its showing that cannot resolve `MyfirebaseMessagingService`, it says that it has no path to go to. can someone help me with this please? If I move it to after my application declaration, it shows up good but I cant generate.

Comment: please post the `build.gradle` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [App Manifest guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) explains the use of class names that start with a period:

> However, if the first character of the string is a period, the
>   application's package name (as specified by the  element's
>   package attribute) is appended to the string.

Is the XML you posted the complete manifest? If so, you are missing the enclosing `manifest` element:

```
<manifest package="com.example.project" . . . >
    <application . . . >
        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService" . . . >
            . . .
        </service>
        . . .
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you have a manifest element, check that it has a package attribute.  Then verify that your service class is defined in that package.

Comment: Thanks! I had to move the MyFirebaseMessagingService class to be directly under the package "com.example.project" to make it work. I also had the closing manifest but for some reason it did not get copied to the question I asked. Thanks again!